# Works with Flex and XML

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a xml structure like this:

```
<root>
    <acteCourantPHP>
        <acCLibel>Soins Semestre 6</acCLibel>
        <acCDeb>2011-12-05</acCDeb>
        <acCFin>2012-06-05</acCFin>
    </acteCourantPHP>
    <montantARelancerPHP>
        <montant>800.00</montant>
        </montantARelancerPHP>
    <montantAttenduPHP>
        <montant>1068.00</montant>
    </montantAttenduPHP>
    <ProcEchPHP>
        <montantProcEch>135.00</montantProcEch>
        <dateProcEch>2011-06-13</dateProcEch>
    </ProcEchPHP>
    <LastRgtPHP>
        <montantLastRgt>665.00</montantLastRgt>
        <dateLastRgt>11/01/2011</dateLastRgt>
    </LastRgtPHP>
```

And I'd like to access to specific value, for exemple I like to access to root.LastRgtPHP.montantLastRgt but I don't know how to do that.

So I hope that someone could help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below more detail to solve that:

```
ldateDebAc.text = myXML.acteFRPHP[0].acteCourantPHP[0].acCDeb;
```

Best regards